# Как запустить фоновую работу php на хостинге

Tags: php, hosting

Есть задача написать ВК бота на long polling. Имеется только хостинг без доступа ssh. Нужно как-то запустить фоновую работу скрипта для long polling. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: а как связано лонгполлинг и фоновая работа (в консоли видимо)?

Comment: Ну как я понял лонгпол работает в фон режиме(ждёт ответа и работает дальше)

Comment: не совсем корректно вы поняли. клиент посылает запрос, сервер его получает, и запрос висит, пока не будет каких-либо данных для отправки клиенту. какие-то фоновые процессы, в т.ч. консольные тут ни при чем.

Comment: А как его запустить?

Answer (score 0):

Так как вы не предоставили информации об ограничениях хостинга (а спросить в комментариях не могу, ведь они мне недоступны), я могу только гадать, но вот первый вариант (возможно не будет работать из-за настроек хостинга):

```php
<?php
if (php_sapi_name() == "cli") {
    // Ваш код
} else {
    exec("php " . __FILE__);
}
```

Второй (то же возможно не подойдёт):

```php
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
// Ваш код
```

И третий: используйте Callback API, подробнее смотрите тут:
https://dev.vk.com/api/callback/getting-started